# How to reverse PNG for drawing

Tags: c++, gdi+

I make game Mario and I want when I use left key < , the character will turn his head to left :-?

How can I implement that ? Thanks for reading this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitMap::RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipY)`